# Graph api explorer returns empty array for another user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the graph API explorer, and I just get the id for any GET operation. The access token has all the fields checked in the `User Data Permissions` and the `Extended Permissions` tab. I've tried it for userids of friends, and non-friends as well. The api works fine when it comes to fetching my own properties i.e,

`/v2.4/me/feed  // works`

`/v2.4/123456789/feed   // only returns 123456789`

`/v2.4/123456789/photos // only returns 123456789`

What am I doing wrong? I've verified certain non friend profiles that have public data, and yet the api returns just the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can´t get access to the feed of a friend, for privacy reasons - and it does not matter if the data is public on Facebook. Friend permissions have been removed with v2.0 of the Graph API. Only use `/me` for access to user data.

Also, check out the API reference to find out which permissions you need, don´t just select all the fields. It´s always very clear which ones you need.

Short answer: You can´t and you´re not supposed to.

Comment: So there's a public album that a person X has, and I'd like to fetch it and display it externally on some page abc.com/picturesOfX. How do I do it? Also, is the sole purpose of the graph api then only crud on one's own profile?

Comment: you don´t. you can´t just grab an album from another user and put it online elsewhere without his authorization. that would be very very wrong, and that´s exactly why it is not possible.

Comment: main rule: you can only access data from users who authorized your app (with the appropriate permissions).